# DevExpress MVC Tab Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, tabcontrol, pagecontrol

I have this page control used in the index file. There are three tabs and each tab will see some of the views. It works fine for the first tab load, however , when I switch to second and third tab, nothing shows. Do I miss anything?

```
@Html.DevExpress().PageControl(
               settings =>
               {
                   settings.Name = "pcClientSideAPI";
                   settings.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
                   settings.ActivateTabPageAction = ActivateTabPageAction.Click;
                   settings.EnableHotTrack = true;
                   settings.Styles.Content.Paddings.Padding = 20;
                   settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                   settings.Height = 200;
                   settings.TabPages.Add("Page1", "page1").SetContent(() =>
                   {

                        Html.RenderPartial("PortfolioChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("OriginationYearChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("MaturityYearChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("PropertyTypeChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("StateChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("RegionChartPartial", Model);
                        Html.RenderPartial("WALChartPartial", Model);


                        Html.Action("SummaryDataPartial", Model);

                   });
                   settings.TabPages.Add("Page2", "page2").SetContent(() =>
                   {

                       @Html.RenderPartial("AnalysisDataPartial", Model);

                   });
                   settings.TabPages.Add("AllData", "page3").SetContent(() =>
                   {

                       @Html.RenderPartial("AllDataPartial", Model);

                   });



               }).GetHtml()
```

Answer (score 1):

just use Html.RenderPartial("......");
@ symbol is not needed . You have added @Html.RenderPartial() instead of Html.RenderPartial. Thats why the the second and third tab is not showing. Just try and give the feedback